# selection sort performing different for reverse order array with duplicates and with no duplicates

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am noting down time for execution of selection sort when i pass it random array, sorted array, and reverse sorted array(with duplicates), and other reverse sorted with no duplicates in it.

according to what i have read selection sort (execution time) should not depend on the data i pass it although it is unstable

i heard that stability has no relation with time complexity so that should not matter.

then why am i getting more time in sorting reverse sorted array with duplicates
and less in no duplicates.

i have checked many times in my code for any mistakes but i couldn't detect any

EDIT ::

i have read the advise and here is the revised version.

here is the code that i am using to generate same array everytime (size 10,000):

```
    srand(1001);//generating same sequance for same seed
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {//producing unsorted array (that have duplicates in it)
        unsorted[i] = (rand() % size) + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {//copying unsorted array into sorted
        sorted[i] = unsorted[i];
    }
    sort(sorted, size);//then sorting it

    for (int i = 0, j = size - 1; i < size; i++, j--) {//copying unsorted array into array with duplicates
        with_dups[j] = sorted[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0, j = size; i < size; i++, j--) {//producing array without duplicate from size (10,000) to 1.
        without_dups[i] = j;
    }
```

here is the code for selection sort :

```
    void sort(int* array, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (array[j] < array[min]) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (min > i) {
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[min];
            array[min] = temp;
        }
    }
    }
```

And this for measuring the time :

```
    struct timeval start, end;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    sort(array, size);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    double timeTaken = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);
    return timeTaken;
```

And this is the output it generates :

```
times taken for sorted                           :    103024
times taken for unsorted                         :    103795
times taken for reverse array with duplicates    :    151721
times taken for reverse array without duplicates :     98674
```

so my question is as selection sort don't depend on data i provide then why am i getting different time in last 2 cases
they should be near about same.....

this difference in time start with value larger then 1000.
and this difference increases as i increase size of array

here is the whole code (just in case anyone needs) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>

void sort(int* array, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (array[j] < array[min]) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (min > i) {
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[min];
            array[min] = temp;
        }
    }
}

double getComplex(int* array, int size) {
    struct timeval start, end;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    sort(array, size);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    double timeTaken = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);
    return timeTaken;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const int size = 10000;

    int* unsorted = new int[size];
    int* sorted = new int[size];
    int* with_dups = new int[size];
    int* without_dups = new int[size];

    srand(1001);//generating same sequance for same seed
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {//producing unsorted array (that have duplicates in it)
        unsorted[i] = (rand() % size) + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {//copying unsorted array into sorted
        sorted[i] = unsorted[i];
    }
    sort(sorted, size);//then sorting it

    for (int i = 0, j = size - 1; i < size; i++, j--) {//copying unsorted array into array with duplicates
        with_dups[j] = sorted[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0, j = size; i < size; i++, j--) {//producing array without duplicate from size (10,000) to 1.
        without_dups[i] = j;
    }

    printf("times taken for sorted                           : %9.0f\n", getComplex(sorted, size));
    printf("times taken for unsorted                         : %9.0f\n", getComplex(unsorted, size));
    printf("times taken for reverse array with duplicates    : %9.0f\n", getComplex(with_dups, size));
    printf("times taken for reverse array without duplicates : %9.0f", getComplex(without_dups, size));

    delete[] unsorted;
    delete[] sorted;
    delete[] with_dups;
    delete[] without_dups;
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE :

ohk wow i didn't knew that we can optimize our code on compilation
when i run the optimized version (option "-O" ) it gives almost same time on

linux(vmware ubumtu 19.03 with gcc 8.3.0)
i.e. :

```
//for 10,000
times taken for sorted                           :    103892
times taken for unsorted                         :    104955
times taken for reverse array with duplicates    :    104091
times taken for reverse array without duplicates :    104110
```

and i compiled same program on windows (with option "-O") (that has gcc 8.2.0)
it gives :

```
//for 10,000
times taken for sorted                           :     25935
times taken for unsorted                         :     25962
times taken for reverse array with duplicates    :     80749
times taken for reverse array without duplicates :     25964
```

i also ran it using option -O2, -O3 it gives different run times on every optimization levels

so i assume this is one of the cases that program behaves differently on different compiler

is this kind of behaviour unpredictable or is there a proper explanation to this???

Comment: Advice -- Don't sort random numbers.  Sort a known set of numbers first, and keep sorting those numbers until you get your program working.  Once you have your program working, then introduce random numbers.  Trying to sort random numbers on code that doesn't work is not effective, as the data keeps changing every time you run the program, thus making debugging the code a moving target.  Your code should just be calling `sort` with a known array, instead of all of the busy work of creating random arrays (plus it would make your code smaller, i.e. a [mcve]).

Comment: So what compiler, compiler version and compiler options are you using? On what architecture are you running the program? Presented values are for the array of how big in size?

Comment: i cant compile on windows cos of "gettimeofday();" so i am running it in vmware ubuntu 19.03 compiler version 8.3.0 , architecture is x86_64 and presented values are of size 10,000....   i also tried running  on my friends pc which has ubuntu and it gives same result that one is also 64bit

Comment: oh wait sorry it was only giving me warning and not error so i tried running and it still gives same(near about) output... on windows compiler version is 8.2.0 and 64bit arch....

Comment: I guess that the compiler is gcc, is it? What compiler options are you using?

Comment: compiler is gcc on linux and mingw on windows (sorry for so many coments)

Comment: i don't understand what u mean by compiler options i googled it and i assume these are some options you have to give if so the i am not giving any options and they should be default

Comment: gcc has [many compiler options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html). Make sure you compile with optimizations enabled `-O` or `-O2`. Are the results you posted run on an idle machine with program compiled with optimizations enabled?

Comment: i have updated post with info after optimization on and it gives weird output is this explainable????

Comment: Your selection sort algorithm is correct. It also iterates the same number of times regardless what you are sorting. While there may be a few clock-cycles difference depending on the branch-prediction in the `min` and `j` comparisons -- that will be in the noise. The most likely culprit is that some other task (or combination of tasks) is also demanding clock cycles when your code is running resulting in different timings regardless of the sort. With gcc, always include `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2` minimum for warnings and optimizations `-O3` and `-Ofast` further optimize.

Comment: I'll also add that results will vary wildly from machine to machine given the differences in I/O, processors, processor scheduling, etc... For a 10,000 int random array, it can be as much as `38222 (us)` (selection sort) and `475 (us)` (`std::sort`) on one machine to `314204 (us)` (selection sort) and `1043 (us)` (`std::sort`) and on any machine it can vary by 90% depending on processor demand at the time of sorting. Example [selection v. std::sort](http://susepaste.org/https://susepaste.org/95731501)